# libnice-0.13.0 cross compilation using glib 2.28.7

Tags: cross-compiling, glib, libnice

I am cross-compiling libnice-0.13.0 for arc-linux-uclibc host on ubuntu 14.04. But it fails out with this error trace

Making all in socket

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/tars/libnice-0.1.13/socket'
  CC       socket.lo
In file included from ../agent/stream.h:47:0,
                 from ../agent/agent-priv.h:92,
                 from socket.c:45:
../agent/component.h:163:8: error: field 'io_mutex' has incomplete type
 GMutex io_mutex;
```

I currently have glib 2.28.7 cross compiled libraries where GMutex types are defined. how do I approach it?

Answer (score 1):

You need GLib 2.32 or newer for support for statically defined `GMutex`es. libnice 0.1.13 requires GLib 2.30 (which is an error: it should require 2.32), so you should already have had a `configure` failure from libnice about that.

GLib 2.28 is seriously old (it was released in 2011). You should upgrade.

Comment: Yes, it did. I tried cross-compiling glib versions >= 2.32.0 . But couldn't do it.